# Cartoon where main character has this weird blue or yellow soul core that can fuse with a big blue/yellow/white monster

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

This Cartoon or anime was on **Netflix** back during the **beginning of 2016** (not released that year I think).

I can remember some scenes: during the first or second episode, the main character is the only one who can see him and the monster broke his bed. Also he might fight big spider aliens during the beginning.